# Number Restriction after decimal point in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to restrict the number of digits after the decimal point using "onkeyup" even in javascript?

I want to restrict the number of digits after the decimal point based on an input already given in the page. if i give the input as 3 then the digits after the decimal points should be only 3. for this i need to use javascript so that at runtime itself output is shown to user and the user should not be able to enter more than 3.

Comment: You can find it here [http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
your_number = (your_number).toFixed(3);
```

Comment: @user2246674 Okay, didn't know that... It seemed to work fine when I tried it on some arbitrary numbers. Thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `toFixed` method:

```
var withDecimals = (1*value).toFixed(numberOfDecimals);
```

Multiplying by 1 makes sure that we are dealing with a number and not some other object, like a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `toFixed(Your number)`  for that

Answer (score 0):

The objectvalue is the current inputtext object where value is entered. id is the object value of the field where precision(no of digits after decimal) is entered.

function decimalRestriction(objectValue,id)
                             {
                             var precision=document.getElementById(id).value;
                            var value=objectValue.value;
                            if(value.match('.'))
                              {
                                var decimaldigits=value.split('.');
                                if(decimaldigits[1].length > precision)
                                    objectValue.value= decimaldigits[0]+ '.' + decimaldigits[1].substring(0, precision);
                                }
        }